# How to disable the automatic screen-centering of input and contenteditable elements in mobile iOS web browser

Tags: css, ios, accessibility, touch, centering

I have a matrix of contenteditable `p` elements centered on screen. When any one of the cells in this matrix is tapped,  iPhone's web browser centers that cell on the screen, so that the matrix is constantly shifting around, left and right, up and down. I suppose this could be an accessibility feature, but in the specific context of my design, the page is being made less accessible for everyone. How to disable this automatic screen-centering of the focused element?

NOTE: So far only able to reproduce the vertical screen-centering with my snippet here. I will be adding additional css to reproduce the left-right shifting.

```css
body {text-align: center

}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row {
  
  height: 100px;
}

p[contenteditable="true"] {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;

}

p[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
      <p contenteditable="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried to copy this code to a playpen but I don't think I'm seeing what you are. Perhaps you can create a working example on jsfiddle or codepen so that I can access it directly from my iphone.

Comment: @slugolicious: Thank you for doing that! I  have found the culprit (it was me) and was coming back here to edit the question. It was a meta tag.  Just not sure which one at this point.